# How can I get session variables to persist across header redirects?

Tags: php, html, sql

**How can I get session variables to persist across header redirects?**

My header redirect looks like this: `header("Location:./content/user_dash.php");`

I have `session_start();` at the top of every page.

I have tried before my header redirect `session_regenerate_id(true);`

I have tried before my header and after session_regenerate_id redirect `session_write_close();`

I have tried `exit(0);` and `die();` after my header redirect;

I have tried `header("Location:./content/user_dash.php?PHPSESSID=".session_id());`

If I INCLUDE the end page it works (But I cannot use this) and when I change it to redirect my variables stop working. I tested this with a foreach loop through $_SESSION and it prints when INCLUDING the page, but doesn't on redirect.

I'm kinda pulling my hair out over this because I really do need to use session variables after redirects.

File Structure:

index.php = submits login form => login_code.php = redirects after setting session vars => user_dash.php echos vars and nothing shows (empty vars, if statement to echo if isset)

I have removed the redirects and even simple hyperlinks aren't carrying my session variables to the next page.

**Live HTTP Header:**

```
*serverinfo*/login_code.php

POST *serverinfo*/login_code.php HTTP/1.1
Host: server
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: *serverinfo*
Cookie: PHPSESSID=im7kid3isj1q9ft03a68s6d5i3
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 29
username=user&password=pass
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: text/html
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.10, ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 03 May 2012 16:24:54 GMT
Content-Length: 159
----------------------------------------------------------
*serverinfo*/content/admin_dash.php

GET *serverinfo*/content/admin_dash.php HTTP/1.1
Host: server
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: PHPSESSID=im7kid3isj1q9ft03a68s6d5i3

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: text/html
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.10, ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 03 May 2012 16:24:54 GMT
Content-Length: 3474
```

Comment: `refresh` is not an official HTTP header. It's Netscape-proprietary. Don't depend on it working.

Comment: it shouldn't affect sessions, since those are done via cookies. But if the cookie settings are incorrect, doing a redirect could cause the session cookie to be "lost".

Comment: Can you place a basic structure of your PHP code, to better understand where's the failure ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to debug your application.

It could be a surprise for you, but debugging takes most of the programmers time. So, time to learn some of the real programmers job.

```
header("Location:./content/user_dash.php?".session_name()."=".session_id());
```

used along with `session_write_close()` is a most bulletproof way

if it's still not working start debugging it.

- check the session file
- check the cookies
- check ini settings
- check session id in the user_dash.php - is it the same?
- check if you really lose all your session or may be just one variable

thank you for the ini settings. 
I can see 2 suspicious ones

- session.use_only_cookies On  means sending SID via url will have no effect. check session cookies AGAIN
- session.cache_expire    180 180 is way too small.

and I may overlooked some as I got not paid for the debugging your app and I have my own job to be done. 
So, I'd just suggest to make all settings default and never touch them until you got to know what are you doing certainly

Comment: I've tried some steps, I do a foreach loop to check through $_SESSION variables, doesn't show anything after the redirect, but if I INCLUDE my page it works.

Comment: Session id's match. Cookies work or else including the page would fail. Nothing prints on redirect with foreach loop so yes $_SESSION is more than likely empty. What ini settings am I looking for?

Comment: `Cookies work or else including...` sorry dude, your includes are not my concern. SESSION COOKIES is what you have to check. Understand? It is not includes but sessions that doesn't work. I wonder though, (what architecture binds together includes and cookies). All ini settings having `session` word in it. Does your session work with simple hyperlink by the way?

Comment: Well I had assumed a simple hyperlink would keep the session variables due to the include working but no, not even a hyperlink works.

Comment: YES, EXACTLY because of **session.use_only_cookies On**

Comment: So that setting is preventing $_SESSION and session_id from getting passed? How would I fix my issue of variables not passing?

Comment: it preventing session_id from getting passed VIA HYPERLINK. either check your cookies as i suggested a day ago or turn this setting off

Comment: I would check them if I knew what I was looking for, I know the save path is C:\windows\temp , but what should the filenames be? I'm not seeing anything related to the site name, and all the files updated today aren't it.

Comment: I told you to check cookies, not files. however, files are named after the session id - a long hexdecimal string in the name cannot be missed. you should also turn error reporting on in case your session issue some warnings but you don't see them.

Comment: well if you are vague, people won't get the gist of what you mean, a cookie as I understand it is variable data saved to file on the users computer. Were you asking me to check my $_COOKIE array? I set error_reporting(E_ALL); on my pages and no errors.

Comment: The only thing set in my $_COOKIE is the session ID.

Comment: Also, all settings are at default in my INI, I haven't touched them which is part of why I'm confused that I'm having any issues

Comment: ah no. I mean a real cookie - an HTTP header. you have to see what headers your server set and what headers browser returns back. I am using LiveHTTPHeaders firefox plugin but there are plenty of tools. Anyway, C:\windows\temp is a SERVER-side SESSION files folder, have nothing in common with CLIENT-side COOKIE storege folder. Browsers never store session cookie on the disk by the way

Comment: ok, I'll grab firefox and that plugin and see what I get be back in a min

Comment: why did you accept the answer? got your sessions to work? what was the problem then?

Comment: I accepted it because questioning my headers helped me find part of the issue, the variables aren't being saved to the cookie at all but the session id is, I'm opening a new question since fixing that is different from this original question.

Comment: wait, session variable shouldn't be stored in cookies. they have to be stored in a file on the server. only session iod have to be passed in cookies. or some different cookie variables you're talking about

Comment: when I set $_SESSION['firstname']="bob"; that should be persistent with the session across pages, I assumed when its set to use only cookies it saves it in the session cookie.

Comment: oh no. use only cookies means use only cookies to pass the session id. that's why your hyperlink doesnt work. the session data always stays in a file

Comment: i'd start checking the files in C:\windows\temp

Comment: I did but theres nothing there for ASP session files (I am using IIS 7 with PHP 5)

Comment: And even this code `<?php
session_start();
$counter = isset($_SESSION['counter']) ? $_SESSION['counter'] : 0;
$counter++;
print "You have visited this page $counter times during this session";
$_SESSION['counter'] = $counter;
?>` doesn't work either.

Comment: you don't need no ASP session files. you need PHP session files

Comment: I fixed my issue by setting security permissions on the windows/temp folder to include iis 7

Answer (score 3):

Put the `session_start()` before any other code including plain text.

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
Hello<?php echo " ".$_SESSION['firstname']." ".$_SESSION['lastname'];?>.
```

Comment: I have a script called login_session.php that I include at the top of every page that does this.

Comment: Then why are you calling it again in the code you posted in your question?

Comment: Do you redirect to another domain?

Comment: @Event_Horizon, To clarify, put `session_start()` at the top of every PHP page where you are accessing session variables.

Comment: Well, header() has some issues with session variables, please read: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php#100282

Comment: @Zuul I'm pretty sure thats only related to using Location: because when using URL= the Session ID still gets passed unlike Location: , maybe this is where I am having my issue but how else would I redirect the page?

Comment: Usually I don't redirect, I use a simple if to either include the file A or B, ex:     if (user_logged()) { require(xpto.php); } else { require(login.php) }

Comment: @Zuul I don't know if includes are going to work for what I'm doing but it did seem to keep session variables then at the very least.

Answer (score 0):

I have found part of my issue my $_SESSION variables though being set are not being saved to the cookie along with the session id. Posting new question on that specific issue.

Answer (score 0):

WE can fix this issue in two way

i .  in Firefox browser setting change character Encoding to "UTF-8"

ii . By PHP code at the page add

`<?php header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); ?>`

which you going to post

Thanks,

Suresh Ramakrishnan

Answer (score -1):

Dealing with redirects and header() + refresh / location, may cause the session_id to be updated, depending on the PHP structure used:

By experience, I've found that naming the session does help addressing the values since the session_name prevents the session_id from being refreshed:

---

Read About it: http://pt2.php.net/session_name

---

**PHP BEFORE ALL ELSE**

```
// If session is not set, this will set it up with the defined name.
// Session is then initialized.
define("CONF_SESSION_NAME", 'my_session_named');
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
    session_name(CONF_SESSION_NAME);
    session_start();
}
```

In my experience, this as avoided session collision from multiple platforms on the same location, and did help going around the header() issues.

Comment: Would that have to be on every page?

Comment: Yes, but place that inside a file and call that file either on your main file (first thing to be done), or if you redirect much, call it on every file. (keep in mind that session_name MUST BE always before the session_start)

Comment: @Event_Horizon, just added a new answer that seams to deal with your particular problem! Never the less, the content of this answer is valid, since this indeed has solve my problem in the past!!

Answer (score -1):

After reading a little bit about this particular problem, I've noticed that on [bugs.php.net](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=14636), there as been a great deal of discussion about this.

The solution found in one of does discussions regarding this particular problem was to redirect the user using a META Refresh:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://example.com/">
```

**Quoting:**

*For PHP to be able to "find" a previously set session variable, it must be able to identify the client, right? Well, the default method used to accomplish this is via a cookie set when you initiate the session. Since it appears you are redirecting the user to the member's only page using the Location header on the same page the session is initiated, the PHPSESSID cookie will not be set. Thus, once the user arrives at the member's only page, PHP won't be able to identify the user. Their session variable is still there, but PHP won't give it to a stranger. :)*

*Basically, in your HTTP reponse that includes the Set-Cookie header, it needs to be a regular 200 OK response and not a protocol level redirection. If you absolutely have to have the behavior you're going for here, you're going to have to use a meta refresh for the redirection. Yes, it's not as cool, but it's the only way to set a cookie and redirect the client in the same response. Otherwise, you'll have to pass the value of the cookie on the URL, which might be a good option for you actually.*

Comment: This redirects but still doesn't keep the variables for some reason, they aren't set after redirect.

Comment: I have also added my php.ini session settings.