# Session variable content changes when form refreshes in PHP

Tags: php

suppose I have two users in the SQL database. In the table column `authority` one is the `Administrator` and the other is `user`.

My issue is if I log in as the Administrator, before the form refreshes, the `$_SESSION['Authentication']` echoes 'Administrator', but after the form refreshes $_SESSION['Authentication']` echoes as 'user'.

Where have I gone wrong in my code which result the `$_SESSION['Authentication'] = 'user'` whereas it should be `$_SESSION['Authentication'] = 'Administrator'` **after the form refreshes**?

**Code :**

```
Session started at the beginning.... 
then this follows.

<?php

include ("connect_db/index.php"); 
if(isset($_SESSION['loggedUser']))
    {
    echo "<form action='signoff/index.php'><div id='four'>Welcome&nbsp". $_SESSION['loggedUser']."&nbsp;! &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type='submit' name='soff' id='soff' class='sout' value='Sign off'></div></form>";
    echo "You are the : ".$_SESSION['Authentication']." of the site.";
    }
else
    { 
    ?><div id='one'><?php
        echo "
        <div id='u2'>
                <form name='form1' method='post' action='''>
                  <table border='1' style='width:520px; bordercolor:#FFFFFF;'>
                    <tr>
                      <td style='width:30px;'>User&nbsp;Name:&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                      <td style='width:80px;'><label for='textfield'></label>
                        <input type='text' maxlength='12' name='UnameZoom' id='UnameZoom' class='txss'></td>
                      <td style='width:30px;'>&nbsp;Password:&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                      <td style='width:80px;'><label for='txss'></label>
                        <input type='password' maxlength='12' name='PwordZoom' id='PwordZoom' class='txss'></td>
                      <td>&nbsp;<input type='submit' name='loggedUser' id='loggedUser' class='mylog' value='Login'></td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </form>
                <p>&nbsp;</p>
                <p>&nbsp;</p>

        </div>";    
    ?></div><?php

    if(isset($_POST['loggedUser']))
        {
            ?><div id='two'><?php
            $un = $_POST['UnameZoom'];
            $pw = $_POST['PwordZoom'];

            if($un=='' || $pw == '')
            {echo "<div id='three'>Empty Fields</div>";} 
            else {

                    $SQL = "SELECT pword FROM users WHERE username='$un'";
                    $resultA = mysqli_query($db,$SQL) or die ("SQL Error!!!");
                    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultA);

                    if($pw == $row['pword'])
                    {
                        $resultB = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT fname AS Lna FROM users WHERE username='$un'"); 
                        $rowB = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultB); 
                        //$sum = $rowB['Lna'];
                        $_SESSION['loggedUser'] = $rowB['Lna'];

                        $resultC = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT authority AS Auth FROM users WHERE username='$un'"); 
                        $rowC = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultC); 
                        unset($_SESSION['Authentication']);
                        $_SESSION['Authentication'] = $rowC['Auth'];


                        header("refresh:3;");
                        //echo "<div id='four'>Welcome&nbsp". $_SESSION['loggedUser']."&nbsp!</div>";

                    }
                    else
                    {
                    echo "<div id='three'>No user found</div>";
                    }
                }   
                ?></div><?php
        }   
    }
?>
```

// this is where I'm trying to echo

```
 <div id="contentLog">
   <?php
if(isset($_SESSION['Authentication']))
   {echo $_SESSION['Authentication'];}
    ?>
```

Comment: You couldn't break this down into a simpler use case scenario? How much troubleshooting have you done?

Comment: @JohnConde Hi John I have tried taking out the 'header("refresh:3;");'. Then it works. Works means S_SESSION['Authentication'] stops at equaling to 'Administrator'. But if I keep it the original as posted above, when the form refreshes the authentication changes to 'user' for some reason which I can't figure out. As per my understanding once a value is put in to a session variable even if the browser refreshes the value remain  unchanged?

Comment: `Session started at the beginning.... ` -- how is that being done? Can you show us the actual code?

Comment: @AmalMurali it's like this..  <?php session_start(); ?> then some html and then the above posted

Comment: Turn on error reporting and see if that changes anything: `ini_set('display_errors',1); 
 error_reporting(E_ALL);` -- add this to the VERY top of your script(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `header("refresh:3;");` makes me suspicious. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10418509/how-can-i-get-session-variables-to-persist-across-header-redirects) might be relevant. Add [`session_write_close()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php) before you call `header()`? Echo [`session_id()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php) to see if the refresh creates a new blank session or if you have a logic error.

Answer (score 0):

please use this condition

```
if($_POST['loggedUser'] != "")
{

}
```